# Is there a way to animate BlendShape keys through scripts?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I thought about how can I get "my carpet" rolled on a certain distance. I made 3D model in Blender and animated it using ShapeKeys and then I imported it into Unity and got everything working. Only thing now that left me struggling is how to animate carpet so that when I score certain amount of point "my carpet" rolls out according to that same score. I found some code for that, but I can't find what is a propertyName for Blend shapes in SkinnedMeshRenderer type. Here is my code...

```
public class AnotherTestingScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        Animation anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
        AnimationCurve curve;

        // create a new AnimationClip
        AnimationClip clip = new AnimationClip();
        clip.legacy = true;

        Keyframe[] keys;
        keys = new Keyframe[3];
        keys[0] = new Keyframe(0.0f, 0.0f);
        keys[1] = new Keyframe(100f, 100f);
        curve = new AnimationCurve(keys);
        clip.SetCurve("", typeof(SkinnedMeshRenderer), "Blend Shape.Key 1", curve);

        // now animate the GameObject
        anim.AddClip(clip, clip.name);
        anim.Play(clip.name);
    }
}
```

Where it says: "clip.SetCurve("", typeof(SkinnedMeshRenderer), "Blend Shape.Key 1", curve);"
I think that there is a problem with propertyPath, I cannot find the right way to call it. So if you have better solution to my entire problem it would mean a lot to me, and if you have the name of propertyName for BlendShapes thank you very much!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Go into your animationclip and check the name of the property yourself. You can also check [this](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/setting-up-blendshapes-in-unity#) unity tutorial.